# apostrophe in ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I need to build the following command in linux using ProcessBuilder:

```
sudo packit -t UDP -S 1000 -D 1200 -s 127.0.0.1 -d 192.168.1.1 -c 5 -n 12345 -p '0x 80 64 45 78 00 00 27'
```

I tried with the following code:

```
commands.add("sudo"); commands.add("packit");
commands.add("-t"); commands.add("UDP");
commands.add("-S"); commands.add("1000");
commands.add("-D"); commands.add("1200");
commands.add("-s"); commands.add("127.0.0.1");
commands.add("-d"); commands.add("192.168.1.1");
commands.add("-c"); 
String a = "5"; commands.add(a);
String b = "-n 12345"; commands.add(b);
String c = "-p '0x 80 64 45 78 00 00 27'"; commands.add(c);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
Process process = pb.start();
```

There isn't syntax error but the result is not same with terminal's result.
When I delete `String c = "-p '0x 80 64 45 78 00 00 27'"; commands.add(c);`.I get same result with terminal's result. I think the problem is apostrophe ('), please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I think you mean 'apostrophe'? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are wrong:

```
String b = "-n 12345"; commands.add(b);
String c = "-p '0x 80 64 45 78 00 00 27'"; commands.add(c);
```

The option (`-n`, `-p`) is separate from its argument:

```
commands.add("-n"); commands.add("12345");
commands.add("-p"); commands.add("0x 80 64 45 78 00 00 27");
```

Note also the lack of additional quotes there. Those are only needed for the shell.

Comment: Thanks Thomas..!!

'commands.add("-p"); commands.add("0x 80 64 45 78 00 00 27");
String b = "-n 12345"; commands.add(b);'

that's works..just delete the additional quotes..